# I don't know whats the issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn

[image]

I typed all the required imports such as

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

and I still get a value error

Comment: Please don't post the screenshot of the error. Post the entire error as a code in the question along with the code you have.

Comment: I concur with Junkrat. Do not post pictures, post the code (or better yet a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and the full error trace. That being said, the screenshot clearly shows that your column is called `Number of Bears` and you are trying to plot `y="Number_of_Bears"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
example = sns.barplot(x=df["speed"], y=df["Number_of_Bears"], data=df)
```